# Does sklearn have any model type metadata either in the project or outside?

Tags: scikit-learn

For example, it could be useful to have information in the library that allows one to select all tree-based ensemble models that work on regression/classifier tasks with more than one output.

I think users could gradually create this meta-data in the library if it doesn't already exist.

So something like:

```
[model_entry for model_entry in sklearn.meta_info if model_entry.2d_y and model_entry.ensemble]
```

but with better names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make use of the estimator tags to get such information: https://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/develop.html#estimator-tags

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for.